# Adding variables in .txt file with windows batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

Windows batch command in Jenkins. I really need key,value environment on jenkins because I don't want to share my important info's in Github. I have to get them on Jenkins

I tried this one for windows but it is not working.

```
@echo off
(echo token= sample && echo header = https://sample.com && echo baseURI = www.sample.com && echo browser = Chrome && echo environment =MobileWeb)>src/main/resources/Global.properties
```

And this for Mac, which is working

```
echo '
    #Edit this section, if need be 
    token = sample......
    header = https://sample
    baseURI = \sample.com/
    browser = Chrome
    environment =MobileWeb
      '>src/main/resources/Global.properties
```

Please help me for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply:

```bash
@(
    echo #Edit this section, if need be
    echo token = sample
    echo header = https://sample.com
    echo baseURI = www.sample.com
    echo browser = Chrome
    echo environment = MobileWeb
) 1>"src\main\resources\Global.properties"
```

Comment: I tried this one but my syntax is wronged. Thank you soo much :prayyyy